# Delphi 5.0 Begin and END tags - navigation in editor by keyboard shortcut

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am using delphi 5.0 IDE and Delphi code.
How do I navigate to the end of a block?
In Eclipse we have ctrl+Shift+P.
Any insight is appreciated much!

Comment: [`CTRL + Q + K`](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys) ?

Comment: @TLama, I think that is only valid for the current selection. If I understand correctly OT wants to navigate to the end of a begin/end pair. I doubt, that there is such a thing - especially not in such an old version.

Comment: Probably need GExperts or CnPack

Comment: This is a fine example of why it's important to keep even indents in your code (I'm assuming you might need this because it's difficult to see where the end of a block is).

Comment: I don't think GExperts and CNPack even work in versions older than Delphi 7. If you can't see the begin and end on the same screen-full of code, then you need to refactor your code. :-)

Comment: CnPack claim support for D5. GX is D6.

Comment: GExperts v1.22 was the last version to support Delphi 5, it is still available from http://www.gexperts.org/download/. You do realise that Delphi 5 was released in 1999?

Comment: I will try the GExperts now. Thank you guys! Will CTRL+Q+K work in that IDE?

Comment: they both are opensource

I think it would not be extremely hard even to get curent CW or CX and update some features while disabling those that cannot be updated.

I'd say CnWizards has a replacement for syntax highlightning outlining begin/end blocks graphically, and that is very great.